# is there any pure-java or standalone deployable implementation of jarsigner?

Tags: java, jarsigner

I've seen a lot of questions here asking how to deploy an app with jarsigner but without a full JDK. Also some people ask how to programatically do jarsigner tasks.

I was wondering if there is any pure-java implementation of jarsigner or even some standalone and alternate implementation of it, easier to deploy with apps.

(of course, I know that you could just force the user to install a full JDK in the installation process or require an installed JDK)

So my question is if there is such a thing like an alternate jarsigner.

If any good soul could also explain why jarsigner must be always native (because java can be decompiled?), it would be a plus :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executable part of the `jarsigner` tool is just a thin wrapper over a pure Java implementation. In fact it's the *same* wrapper that is used for `java,` `javac,` `javap,` etc.

The real problem you have is that the class files used by `jarsigner` are in `tools.jar,` which isn't present in a JRE.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative tool called **SignApk**. The procedure is very well explained here [How to Sign Android APK or Zip Files](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-sign-apk-zip-files/)

> SignApk.jar is a tool included with the Android platform source
>   bundle, you can download it from here. To use SignApk.jar you have to
>   create a private key with it’s corresponding certificate/public key.
>   To create private/public key pair, you can use Openssl